Help assessing the condition of this horizontal 90 degree wall drain elbow
I am replacing the sink in my bathroom. I pulled the old metal drain pipe out of the wall. It was loosely adhered probably with old rubber cement or whatever the standard was back in the day. I.e., no nut or gasket etc. Switching to PVC now. Two questions.

Will I need to cut open my wall, pull this elbow out and try to install a new one? Due to the rust and corrosion? I'm guessing it's over 20 years old.
If not, how can I clean up then seal the new PVC tube to the opening in the wall?

I only have one top down picture from when I added blocking between studs. Lucky to have this pic. Album below. Thanks all!
https://imgur.com/a/uUH6u5N

How was the old metal elbow attached to the pipe in the wall?  You can't just stick a PVC pipe in the old metal one.

Thanks @Huesmann.

Sorry, hit reply too soon.
I knew the iron elbow had to go, so I bit the bullet and cut my wall open (again, before it was for the wall mounted sink, to add blocking). This is what I found. I see how the old metal sink drain tail pipe would have been compressed in by that nut and gasket.
https://imgur.com/a/YOUmyJe
My new plan is to use a Fernco coupling to connect that male threaded iron pipe to some new PVC. An elbow directly, if I can. I think I should / need to cut the pipe back so the threads aren't there anymore. It's my understanding metal threads into PVC are to be avoided.

Proposed idea of how I am to replace what was there. Existing 1-1/2" iron pipe, cut back behind threads --> Fernco coupling --> 1-1/2" PVC elbow --> 1-1/2" to 1-1/4" PVC bushing OR Slip-Joint Trap Adapter.

Could ream out the galvanized pipe and replace the elbow with a PVC one.

@Huesmann this is what I went with, good idea! Cut off that old pipe past the threads and went with a PVC elbow connected to the old pipe with a Fernco coupling.  All is good as new!
